# Location latitude longitude

Tags: 7, nodes

I am trying to update a website from Drupal 5 to 7 and I have to use location field for one of my content types. On Drupal 5, I can see the latitude and longitude fields but on drupal 7 I can not. Please check the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the Drupal 7 field settings for that location field, make sure you have enabled the longitude and latitude fields.

I believe there is also an option to "allow user to choose co-ordinates".